# SQL Create table error?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, create-table

I use the following sql statement in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE "User"(
    userId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userRoleId int NOT NULL,
    taalId int NOT NULL,
    hotelId int NOT NULL,
    gebruikersnaam varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    wachtwoord varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (userRoleId) REFERENCES UserRole (userRoleId),
    FOREIGN KEY (taalId) REFERENCES Taal (taalId),
    FOREIGN KEY (hotelId) REFERENCES Hotel (hotelId),
    PRIMARY KEY(userId)
 );
```

But i get the follwoing Mysql error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"User"( userId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, userRoleId int NOT
>   NULL, taalI' at line 1

What is going wrong?

Edit: the tables UserRole, Taal and Hotel are created properly without a problem.

Comment: should the table name be within quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape a reserved word, [use backticks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html) not quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` -- <== Notice backticks instead of quotes
( 
    userId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    userRoleId int NOT NULL, 
    taalId int NOT NULL, 
    hotelId int NOT NULL, 
    gebruikersnaam varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
    wachtwoord varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
    email varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (userRoleId) REFERENCES UserRole (userRoleId), 
    FOREIGN KEY (taalId) REFERENCES Taal (taalId), 
    FOREIGN KEY (hotelId) REFERENCES Hotel (hotelId), 
    PRIMARY KEY(userId) 
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
`user`
```

instead of:

```
"User"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's something trivial... but as far as I know you shouldn't use quotes on your table names... try replacing them with backticks.